# problem with displaying parent object with some child objects on the table

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

I have some issues in displaying a list of object that I get it from back-end

This my parent object

```
export class Regle {
  itRegle: number;
  isDemande: boolean;
  dateCreation: string;
  dateFinPrevu: string;
  descriptionRegle: string;
  statutRegle: string;
  typeRegle: string;
  dateSuppression: string;
  profilApplication: Profil;
  environnement: Environnement;
  contrat?: Contrat;
  fonction?: Fonction;
  site?: Site;
  utilisateur?: Utilisateur;
  organisation?: Organisation;
  emploi?: Emploi;
  compteApplication?: CompteApplication;
  compteMultiID?: CompteMultiID;
}
```

This is how I get the list of parent object from the back

```
let _regSubscription=this.regleService.getRegles().subscribe(data=>{
  this.regles=data;
  this.collectionSize=data.length;
},err=>{
  console.log(err);
});
```

And in my template, here is how I display a list of `Regle` on the table

```
<tbody>
  <tr
    mdbTableCol
    *ngFor="
      let rgl of regles
      | filter: term
      | slice
      : (page - 1) * pageSize
      : (page - 1) * pageSize + pageSize
    ">
    <td>{{ rgl.itRegle }}</td>
    <td>{{ rgl.environnement.codeTypeEnvironnement }}</td>
    <td>{{ rgl.contrat.codeTypeContrat }}</td>
    <td>{{ rgl.fonction.codFonction }}</td>
    <td>{{ rgl.site.codeSite }}</td>
    <td>{{ rgl.organisation.codeOrganisation }}</td>
    <td>{{ rgl.emploi.codeEmpoi }}</td>
    <td>{{ rgl.isDemande }}</td>
    <td>{{ rgl.dateCreation | slice: 0:10 }}</td>
    <td>{{ rgl.dateFinPrevu }}</td>
    <td>{{ rgl.statutRegle }}</td>
    <td>{{ rgl.descriptionRegle }}</td>
    <td>
      <a class="clickable" (click)="onEdit('Groupe', rgl)"><i class="fas fa-edit">edit</i></a>
      |
      <a  class="clickable" (click)="onDelete('Groupe', rgl)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt">delete</i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The problem is that all the child objects of the parent object `Regle` do not necessarily exist so when the table is displayed I have the following error:

> RegleComponent.html:154 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property codeTypeContrat' of null
>
> ```
> at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (RegleComponent.html:155)
> at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:45294)
> at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44277)
> at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
> at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44594)
> at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44272)
> at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
> at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44594)
> at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44272)
> at callViewAction (core.js:44637) View_RegleComponent_6 @ RegleComponent.html:154 RegleComponent.html:154 ERROR CONTEXT
> ```
>
> DebugContext_

The child object `Contrat` is like this :

```
export class Contrat{
  public  itContrat:number;
  public  codeTypeContrat:string;
  public  libelleTypeContrat:string;
  public  descriptionTypeContrat:string;
  public  dateSuppression:Date;
  public  trtTypeContrat:string;
  public  isLimite:string;
}
```

2 - My second problem is that I cannot display the `Regle` in the edit form when I click on the edit button in the `Regle` table, knowing that the child objects of the `Regle` are represented on a select in the form ?

Do you have any idea of how I can do that?

The part of my form :

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formCreate.value)" #formCreate="ngForm">
  <fieldset disabled>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="profilSelect" class="col-2 col-form-label">Profil*</label>
      <div class="col-8">
        <ng-select
          [items]="selectedRegle.profilApplication"
          [bindLabel]="'codeProfilApplication'"
          name="profil"
          placeholder="Select"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedRegle.profilApplication"
          [disabled]="true">
        </ng-select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="environnementSelect" class="col-2 col-form-label">Environnement*</label>
    <div class="col-8">
      <ng-select
        [items]="environnements"
        [bindLabel]="'libelleTypeEnvironnement'"
        name="environnement"
        placeholder="Select"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedRegle.environnement">
      </ng-select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row"  *ngIf="selectedRegle.typeRegle==='ORGANISATION'">
    <label for="contratSelect" class="col-2 col-form-label">Contrat</label>
    <div class="col-8">
      <ng-select
        [items]="contrats"
        [bindLabel]="'libelleTypeContrat'"
        name="contrat"
        placeholder="Select"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedRegle.contrat">
      </ng-select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

In advance thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

On your first problem, I have something similar, so I used two approaches, depending on what worked better: One is to put it as optional in the html, something like:

```
 <td>{{ rgl?.environnement?.codeTypeEnvironnement }}</td>
```

Or also a function that returns the things after checking if it exists, kind of

```
<td>{{ getMyCodeTypeEnvironnement() }}</td>

...

getMyCodeTypeEnvironnement() {
  if (rgl !== undefined) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I don't know if thats good practice, but it works for me... On your second issue, I have unfortunately not really any clue. Hope this helps anyway.

Comment: You should not use methods on template, this methods will be executed till the component is destroy, so if there is strong operation in it, it will result on bad performances. Just use for example `<div *ngIf="rgl !== undefined">...</div>`

Comment: See? You allways learn...
Learned something again! I have exactly the issue of the methods being called all the time, until now without much performance problems, but is definitively a much improved way! Thanks!!